# Use of Redis for caching rss feeds - several kb to multi MB

Tags: caching, web-applications, redis

I have a web application that serves RSS feeds (xml).  The size of feeds served varies from several kb to multi megabyte.  Currently I store the xml for these feeds in Redis; there is simply one Redis cache object per feed.  Upon receiving a request for the feed, the web application retrieves the cache object from Redis and serves it to the user.  The RSS feeds in Redis are updated between 1 and 20 times per day, as the RSS feeds get updated content.

Is this an appropriate use of Redis?

Comment: I think it's a fine use for redis, but that's just my opinion. Though, if the feeds are update so rarely, you could just as easily use the file system.

Comment: Problem with file system is I can't count on it being there.